# jquery automatically scrolling table rows but with table header fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are code sample/plugins out there to make the header fixed and the table scrollable. But I want to achieve is **automatically** scrolling table data rows once it's loaded, but keep the header fixed.

Is there a plugin/jquery code to do just that?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table won't scroll

- You can create a fake table header that float on top of the table
- Use CSS to separate table header and make it always float http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

Put the table body in a fixed height div with overflow: auto. Then write an interval function to make it scroll

```
setInterval(function(){
   $('#scrolldiv').scrollTop($('#scrolldiv').scrollTop() + 10); //Just an example
}, 100)
```

Comment: so the "scrollTop" function only applies to browser's scroll bar?

Comment: No, it's apply to element that have scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

There is jQuery plugin for that: http://fixedheadertable.com/

integrate it with this code from this site: http://oncemade.com/animated-page-scroll-with-jquery and you'll be able to achieve that.